# Getting the OS User through SQL Authentication

Tags: sql-server

I know I can grab the user's OS ID with the following but that only works if the user is logged in via windows authentication.

```
select nt_username from master..sysprocesses
```

Is there anyway to do the same if the user is logged in with SQL Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logged in via SQL authentication, there's no way to identify the user in SQL Server. All you got is the SQL Server user ID.

BTW, you should use the SQL Server built-in security functions to get this information, not the system tables:

- CURRENT_USER
- SESSION_USER
- SYSTEM_USER
- USER_ID()
- USER_NAME()
- SUSER_ID()
- SUSER_NAME()

See Books Online for the details.